# Adding a Calendar to a SyncAdapter Account for API 10 (2.3.3) to API (14)?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-calendar, android-syncadapter

I have created a SyncAdapter along with authentication.  Now that I am able to add a synced account to my device, I would like that account to be able to have Calendars associated to it.

- My SyncAdapter syncs to a custom calendar webserver
- I plan to support **Android 2.3.3 to 4.x**

I know that before API 14 the Android's internal calendar store wasn't officially supported for developers and that no ContentProvider existed.  But is the Calendar database schema the same from 2.3.3 and on?  Specifically, could I potentially write a custom Calendar ContentProvider for 2.3.3 and have it properly function on 4.0+?

Is there anywhere I could obtain a database schema for the Android calendars for 2.3.3 and 4.0 to investigate this?

Additionally, is it the Calendar database that stores which SyncAdapter account a given Calendar is associated to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this tool -- **http://www.cellobject.net/Tools/CellObjectSQLiteXMLBrowser.aspx** to visualize the Calendar DB. **This will give the schema of the Calendar DB.**

**Specifically, could I potentially write a custom Calendar ContentProvider for 2.3.3 and have it properly function on 4.0+?**

- Yes, you can use contentProviders. (Just check whether the columns that you are going to use are present in both)

**But is the Calendar database schema the same from 2.3.3 and on?**

- Yes, most of the items are same **but there are column_name changes**. you can check it here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.EventsColumns.html

Hope this helps.. Let me know if you are looking for something specific